# Device to act as intermediary step to strengthen wireless signal to other building

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I live in a guest house on my landlord's property and use his wireless network. The problem is that while the signal is fairly strong if I'm standing right outside of his house on the patio, the guest house is far enough (~40 feet) that I'm getting about 10% of the download speed on a good day.

We tried one of those things (sorry for the vague language, I know very little about this kind of technology) that you plug into the wall in order to catch the network directly but couldn't get it to work.
The lights were green and blinking on the device as they should, but no internet. His guess was that there are "breakers" in between the main house and the guest house and they're what's causing the problem.

I was hoping to find a way to catch the signal with perhaps some kind of antenna or maybe another router that we could put in front of one of the guest house's windows (so that the signal wouldn't have to go through the walls as much). Basically a device that would act as an intermediary and give me a better signal in the guest house.

What would be the best way to go about doing that? Any other solution is welcome as well.

Comment: What model of device did you buy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that you plug into the wall in order to catch the network directly but couldn't get it to work. The lights were green and blinking on the device as they should, but no internet. His guess was that there are "breakers" in between the main house and the guest house and they're what's causing the problem.

There are several different devices with the same general shape, all of which provide their own Wi-Fi signal:

- Wireless extenders / repeaters, which connect to an existing Wi-Fi network over, well, radio.
- Wireless extenders / access points, which connect to an existing network over an Ethernet cable. (Often just the same device as above, set to a different mode.)
- Powerline (HomePlugAV or G.hn) adapters. These have an Ethernet port, but *also* communicate with other such adapters through the mains lines, if you bought another that is. (They are bridges, not routers, so it doesn't matter whether you use Ethernet or powerline as the "input" or "output".)

Of these, *only* the Powerline (G.hn or HomePlug) adapters are affected by circuit breakers, and *only* when actually communicating over the power line to another such adapter. All other types only plug into the wall for mains power and nothing else.

---

The types which have a Wi-Fi uplink either need to be configured through a web browser (to set the main network's name and passphrase), or at least obtain this information through WPS. Make sure you've done that...

(This is needed for other types as well, to configure the network they'll be broadcasting.)

---

Assuming that none of these devices end up working, and that you can't run a cable of any kind:

There exist Wi-Fi bridges specifically for long-range point-to-point connections, like the ones used by WISPs. You configure one to act as an access point, another as a station, put them on your roofs, point at each other (they have directional antennas), and the link can span several kilometers given line of sight. (Ubiquiti has a series, Mikrotik has something or other, LigoWave has things.)

These devices' antennas are more sensitive as well, not just more powerful. So it is possible to get away with just one, either as a client pointed towards your existing wireless network, or as an access point pointed towards the guest house. I have no idea if this is good advice. (Though it's a neat trick having my phone connect to a network that's 500 meters away.)

For vague safety reasons, I would recommend starting at the lowest possible power setting, and slowly tweaking it upwards.